# How to prevent WebBrowser control from stealing focus from other text box in my WPF form

Tags: wpf, focus, webbrowser-control

My WPF app has a window with various text boxes and a WebBrowser control.
The WebBrower control is used to show a web site (I doesn't own) and then a Login button in the WPF window fills the fields in the site from the text boxes.

The problem is that the web site calls focus() method on one of its input fields on load, and that still the focus from the text box in my WPF window. I want the focus to be on the WPF window field and not in the web page within the WebBrowser control.

I tryed calling MyTextBox.Focus() in the WebBrowser's LoadCompleted event, but to no avail. Setting the WebBrowser's IsEnabled or even Visibility properties didn't help either.

Does anyone have an idea how I can overcome this and move the focus to the WPF control instead of the web page input field?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can extend the control site to add IProtectFocus to the site. Try interop the Windows Forms version of the webbrowser control and override the CreateWebBrowserSiteBase method  to provide your own control site.